# removing a rectangle from a jpanel using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel, paintcomponent, rectangles

```
'package javaapplication12;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.*;

/** Bouncing Ball (Animation) via custom thread */
public class JavaApplication12 extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
// Define named-constants
private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 30; // milliseconds
int xx = 200;
int yy = 400;
Shape a1;
Shape a2;
Rectangle2D a3;

Rectangle2D a12;
Rectangle2D a4;
Rectangle2D a5;
Rectangle2D a6;
Rectangle2D a7;
Rectangle2D a8;
Rectangle2D a9;
Rectangle2D a10;
Rectangle2D a11;
Rectangle2D a13;
Rectangle2D a14;
Rectangle2D a15;
Rectangle2D a16;
Rectangle2D a17;
Rectangle2D a18;
Rectangle2D a19;
Rectangle2D a20;
Rectangle2D a21;
Rectangle2D a22;
Rectangle2D a23;
Rectangle2D a25;
ArrayList<Rectangle2D> s = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();

Color c2 = Color.RED;

private DrawCanvas canvas; // the drawing canvas (extends JPanel)

// Attributes of moving object
private int x = 375;     // top-left (x, y)
private int y = 355;
private int size = 20;  // width and height
private int xSpeed = 3;  // moving speed in x and y directions
private int ySpeed = 5;  // displacement per step in x and y


 /** Constructor to setup the GUI components */
public JavaApplication12() {
  canvas = new DrawCanvas();
  canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
  this.setContentPane(canvas);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.pack();
  this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
  this.setVisible(true);
  addKeyListener(this);
  fun();

 // Create a new thread to run update at regular interval
  Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        while (true) {
           update();   // update the (x, y) position

           repaint();  // Refresh the JFrame. Called back paintComponent()

           try {
              // Delay and give other thread a chance to run
              Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);  // milliseconds
           } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        }
     }
  };
  updateThread.start(); // called back run()
}

/** Update the (x, y) position of the moving object */
public void update() {
  x += xSpeed;
  y += ySpeed;
  if (x > CANVAS_WIDTH - size || x < 0) {
     xSpeed = -xSpeed;
  }
  if (y > CANVAS_HEIGHT - size || y < 0) {
     ySpeed = -ySpeed;
  }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    int keycode = ke.getKeyCode();
       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
       {
          xx = xx-15;
       }

       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
       {
         xx = xx+15;
       }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

/** DrawCanvas (inner class) is a JPanel used for custom drawing */
class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);  // paint parent's background
  Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D)g; 


  for(Rectangle2D r : s){
            d.fill(r);
        }
     setBackground(Color.BLACK);

     g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     a1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,size,size);
     a2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(xx,yy,120,10,20,20);

     a25 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,120,100,20);



     d.fill(a1);
     d.setPaint(c2);
      d.fill(a2);

     if(a1.intersects(a3.getBounds()))
     {


         s.remove(a3);ySpeed = -ySpeed;

     }
     if(a1.intersects(a4.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a4);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a5.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a5);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a6.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a6);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a7.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a7);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a8.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a8);ySpeed = -ySpeed;

     }
     if(a1.intersects(a9.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a9);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a10.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a10);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a11.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a11);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a12.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a12);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a13.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a13);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a14.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a14);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
     if(a1.intersects(a15.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a15);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a16.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a16);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a17.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a17);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a18.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a18);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a19.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a19);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a20.getBounds()))
     {
         s.remove(a20);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a21))
     {
         s.remove(a21);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }

     if(a1.intersects(a22))
     {

       s.remove(a21);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }
 collide();
}
}
public final void fun()
{
    a3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,15,100,20);
      a4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,15,100,20);
       a5 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,15,100,20);



       a6 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,15,100,20);
         a7 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,15,100,20);

         a8 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,50,100,20);
           a9 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,50,100,20);
            a10 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,50,100,20);
             a12 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,50,100,20);
              a11 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,50,100,20);

          a13 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,85,100,20);
           a14 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,85,100,20);
            a15 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,85,100,20);
             a16 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,85,100,20);
              a17 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,85,100,20);

          a18 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,120,100,20);
           a19 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,120,100,20);
            a20 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,120,100,20);
             a21 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,120,100,20);
               a22 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,120,100,20);
        s.add(a3);
        s.add(a4);
        s.add(a5);
        s.add(a6);
        s.add(a7);
        s.add(a8);
        s.add(a9);
        s.add(a10);
        s.add(a11);
        s.add(a12);
        s.add(a13);
        s.add(a14);
        s.add(a15);
        s.add(a16);
        s.add(a17);
        s.add(a18);
        s.add(a19);
        s.add(a20);
        s.add(a21);
        s.add(a22);
}

  public void collide()
   {

   if(a2.intersects(a1.getBounds()))
     {
         xSpeed = +xSpeed;
         ySpeed = -ySpeed;

      }
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Run GUI codes in Event-Dispatching thread for thread safety
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        new JavaApplication12(); // Let the constructor do the job

     }
  });

 }
} `
```

Ok I'm new to Java game programming. I'm programming a game that is like a brick breaker

I have a array list which contains some rectangles. I have draw it using a enhanced `for-loop`. My game has a ball and when the ball hits the rectangle it must disappear amd at the same time the ball must takea reverse movement. Everything works fine. But once the rectangle disappears and if the ball goes again to that place the ball takes reverse direction even though the rectangle is not there.

Collison checked using `intersect()` method.

Comment: Collision "Cheched". Hello everyone if any one jas not understood Please let me knw I'm new to this site.I willl explain it better if u want. Please help

Comment: You should have two lists. One for balls and one for rectangles. In your timer, for each iteration of the loop of balls, iterate through the list of rectangles to check for intersection. Use an `Iterator` and not a for loop for this inner iteration, so you can call `iterator.remove()`. After you `repaint()`, you should see the removed if there was a collision

Comment: If you post some code, we may be give you more details about where you may be going wrong with this

Comment: /a1 is the ball and a3 is the rectangle here

if(a1.intersects(a3.getBounds( ))) {

s.remove(a3); //remove from the list ySpeed = -ySpeed; // for reverse movement of the ball

}

//have called this method in the constructor so that irt exectues only ones public void fun() { a3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,15,100,20); s.add(a3); }

and i have the for loop in the paint component method.

Comment: If the ball is reversing its direction where a rectangle 'used' to be, it sounds like the arraylist you are using to draw is not the same underlying arraylist as you are using to check the intersect.

Comment: So what is the solution for this? Plz give me some idea @matt

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing your code properly. If you edit your question, and paste your code in a 'code' block (see this question for a good example of how to present your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013819/how-to-save-only-zip-files-and-remove-other-folders-using-java) then I can probably tell you exactly what your solution is

Comment: I have pasted the whole code. Please have a look test run it . And hope u get a solution for it. Thanks in advance @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for painting the rectangles uses the arraylist 's', and your logic correctly removes them so they disappear.

However, your code for reversing the speed does not take into account whether that rectangle is still in 's' or not. No matter whether a rectangle has been removed from 's', the logic:

```
if(a1.intersects(a3.getBounds()))
```

will always return true if the ball gets to where the rectangle was. You need to do something like:

```
if(s.contains(a3) && a1.intersects(a3.getBounds()))
```

so that after a rectangle is removed, it will not match and bounce.

Also, you have a typo in 'a22':

```
if(a1.intersects(a22))
 {

   s.remove(a21);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
  ySpeed = -ySpeed;
 }
```

should be:

```
if(a1.intersects(a22))
 {
   s.remove(a22);ySpeed = -ySpeed;
 }
```

Another thing to think about, is that if the ball hits right in between two rectangles, it will intersect with both of them, and they will each reverse the ySpeed (so the ball will carry on going straight)

Hope that helps!

Comment: My pleasure :) if the code is now working, please accept the answer :)

Comment: And I have one more doubt @Matt when the prgm is executed the thread is automtically started BUT I want a key listener to initiate the start of the thread. Please help me out.

Comment: I'm not very good at Swing/AWT but I guess you should make updateThread into a class variable and move the method call 'updateThread.start();' from the constructor into the keyPressed method

Comment: What do u mean by a class variable? Plz tell me how to do that @Matt