# How to save only zip files and remove other folders using java?

Tags: java, file, directory, delete-file

Here i have Folder(Books)in that i have 3 sub folders named:**sub1, sub2, sub3** and **sub1 have 2 files**, **sub2 have 3 files**, **sub3 have 4 files**. And **sub1.zip**,**sub2.zip** and **sub3.zip**. I want to **keep only zip files** and **delete sub1, sub2, sub3 folders** of Books. With my code I'm able to delete all inside files of sub1 folder, sub2, sub3 finally all folders becoming empty, then **how can I delete sub1,sub2 and sub3 folders**.

```
public void SaveZipFiles(File destwithouAudio) throws IOException {
    File[] listOfFiles = destwithouAudio.listFiles();
    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
        if (listOfFile.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
        } else {
            File FolderInside = new File(listOfFile.getAbsolutePath());
            File[] listOfFilesInside = FolderInside.listFiles();
            for (File listOfFilesInside1 : listOfFilesInside) {
                File deleteFolder = new File(listOfFilesInside1.getAbsolutePath());
                //System.out.println(""+listOfFilesInside[j]);
                RecursiveDelete(deleteFolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RecursiveDelete method code is:

```
public static void RecursiveDelete(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        if (file.list().length == 0) {
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            String files[] = file.list();
            for (String temp : files) {
                File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);
                RecursiveDelete(fileDelete);
            }
            if (file.list().length == 0) {
                file.delete();
                System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    } else {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("File is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

After deleting all files from **sub1,sub2,sub3** foldersIi need to delete all **sub1,sub2,sub3** folders.

Where to change the code?

Comment: Don't you use Java 7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893205/how-to-replace-file-listfilesfilefilter-filter-with-nio-in-java-7

Comment: your code is working fine and it is deleting empty directories as well

Comment: @Sanjeev,files are deleting inside sub1,sub2.After becoming sub1,sub2 folders empty its remaining.Not deleting sub1,sub2.

Comment: I ran your code on my Windows box it is running fine. are you using some other os?

Comment: As i told sub1,sub2 also has to delete.only i need to show .zip file remaining everyting inside Books folder i have to delete.for the same code i'm able to delete all files inside sub1,sub2.But sub1,sub2 are not deleting,I'm also using windows only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete(); // The directory is empty now and can be deleted.
}
```

then, you could be using

```
public void SaveZipFiles(File destwithouAudio) { 
    File[] deletion = destwithouAudio.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return !name.endsWith(".zip");
        }

    });
    for (File toDelete : deletion) {
        deleteDir(toDelete);
    }
}
```

(using [deleting folder from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java) folder deletion)

Comment: destwithouAudio,this is my main folder where i have all .zip files and subfolders are located @Zahlii